Is this the right greedy strategy for allocating seats?
I am attempting https://open.kattis.com/problems/distributingseats
This problem has been listed as a classical greedy problem in the Competitive Programming Book by Steven & Felix
https://cpbook.net/methodstosolve?oj=kattis&topic=all&quality=all
The hints are
sort; greedy bipartite matching; assign passenger to earliest available row first
The challenge is about figuring the right attribute to sort on
Here is my approach:
It passes only 3/19 test cases
Each passenger has an interval of acceptable rows.
I tried sorting these intervals on end points. Breaking ties by comparing start points.
This approach works on the sample test cases and the one I created in the image.
Need some help with a breaking test case.

import java.util.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int r = scanner.nextInt();
    int c = scanner.nextInt();

    int a, b, s;
    List < int[] > L = new ArrayList < > ();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      a = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
      b = scanner.nextInt() - 1;
      s = scanner.nextInt();
      L.add(new int[] {
        Math.max(0, a - s), Math.min(r - 1, a + s)
      });
    }

    L.sort((x, y) -> {
      if (x[1] == y[1]) {
        return Integer.compare(x[0], y[0]);
      }
      return Integer.compare(x[1], y[1]);
    });

    int ans = 0;
    int idx = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i) {
      for (int j = 0; j < c; ++j) {
        while (idx < L.size() && L.get(idx)[1] < i) {
          ++idx;
        }
        if (idx == L.size()) {
          break;
        }
        if (L.get(idx)[0] <= i && i <= L.get(idx)[1]) {
          ++ans;
          ++idx;
        }
      }
    }

    System.out.println(ans);
  }

}


The code is hard to read. You could use long variable names even if they are called n, r, c in the problem description.
I also wouldn't use Java for this specific problem. It would be easier to write in Java after solving the problem using another language.
A dynamic scripting language with an expressive syntax i.e. Ruby would be easier to write and read with. It makes you more efficient at testing many things until you find the correct answers to your problems.
Using a pen and paper and drawing how it should work can really help, I recommend a 4-colour pen.
You can divide the problem into simpler problems. And then make one function for each of those simpler problems.
If they aren't simple enough, divide again.
You can create structured data to make the problem easier to reason with. So for example, you could have a List<Passenger>
where a Passenger has a preferredPosition, where Position is an object with a row and column integer properties.
Once you resolve the problem, it's always possible to optimize and use a 2D integer array or whatever, but performance is not a concern until it becomes one.
About the problem itself, I would start by finding all the acceptable positions of all passengers.
Then I would start assigning positions to the passengers that have the least possibilities and where those possibilities are the least present in other passengers desires.
One counter-intuitive ("greedy") tip: caring about a passenger's closeness doesn't help with the problem. The farthest position may be the best one to resolve the problem, because the passenger will still "accept" it.
